# Cannot copy old TimeCapsule data as disk formatted HFS+ Case-sensitive

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule, hfs+

I have an elderly TimeCapsule from which I want to copy 500Gb of TimeMachine backups.

When I mount the sparsebundle and try to copy the contents to a new HFS+ partition the process fails as the TimeCapsule drive is formatted Case-sensitive.

I have seen many threads about this online but haven't found a process that works.

The most progress I've made is with Carbon Copy Cloner which seems willing to clone the sparsebundle, but at a speed of 5 megabytes/second over ethernet (giving a completion time of 24 hours give or take).

I don't need to preserve the TimeCapsule itself - just want to get the data onto my new external drive ASAP.

What's the best way forwards?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What version of macOS do you have? You write: "the process fails as the TimeCapsule drive is formatted Case-sensitive". Do you get an error message? If so, can you add it to your question?